# how to Install easy_install Via yum on Linux CentOS Server

Tags: java, php

please tell me how to Install easy_install Via yum on Linux CentOS Server

i tried that in panel command center

> yum install python-setuptools yum

output....

```
 * epel: mirrors.tummy.com
 * base: mirrors.tummy.com
 * updates: centos.mirrors.tds.net
 * addons: mirror.fdcservers.net
 * extras: mirrors.gigenet.com
0 packages excluded due to repository protections
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-setuptools.noarch 0:0.6c9-5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/python26 for package: python-setuptools
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python26.i386 0:2.6.5-6.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libpython2.6.so.1.0 for package: python26
--> Processing Dependency: libffi.so.5 for package: python26
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python26-libs.i386 0:2.6.5-6.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libffi.i386 0:3.0.5-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package                  Arch          Version               Repository   Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 python-setuptools        noarch        0.6c9-5               chl         357 k
Installing for dependencies:
 libffi                   i386          3.0.5-1.el5           epel         21 k
 python26                 i386          2.6.5-6.el5           epel        6.5 M
 python26-libs            i386          2.6.5-6.el5           epel        667 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install      4 Package(s)         
Update       0 Package(s)         
Remove       0 Package(s)         

Total download size: 7.5 M
Is this ok [y/N]: Exiting on user Command
Complete!
```

I've also tried

> yum install python-setuptools-devel

i want to install html5lib

> easy_install html5lib

Comment: You better post that question on http://serverfault.com or http://superuser.com/. http://stackoverflow.com is for programming questions

Comment: you should move on over to ServerFault with this question

Comment: Looks like it worked for you. Understand that you need to call `easy_install` with root privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the "chl" repo and try again. It's in the base repo.